# Log form input to Logstash

Tags: php, logging, logstash

I have a simple form that takes information from a user. Just the basic registration info stuff, e.g. email, first name, last name, etc. I've installed Logstash on another server. I'd want to log the inputs there. Is there any way I can do this? Preferably in XML format?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can save your logs to a file. Then use a [logstash shippe](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/tutorials/getting-started-centralized)r ships all the log to the logstash which at another server.

The prefer format for logstash is JSON. But you can also output to plain text and use logstash API to parse your logs.

Comment: Can I do this programmatically? I'm using PHP. Is there anyway I can trigger this every after submit?